# Nifi Group Content by Given Attributes

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to run a script or a custom processor to group data by given attributes every hour. Queue size is up to 30-40k on a single run and it might go up to 200k depending on the case.

- MergeContent does not fit since there is no limit on min-max counts.
- RouteOnAttribute does not fit since there are too many combinations.

**Solution 1:** Consume all flow files and group by attributes and create the new flow file and push the new one. Not ideal but gave it a try.
While running this when I had 33k flow files on queue waiting.

`session.getQueueSize().getObjectCount()`

This number is returning 10k all the time even though I increased the queue threshold numbers on output flows.

**Solution 2:** Better approach is consume one flow file and and filter flow files matching the provided attributes

```java
final List<FlowFile> flowFiles = session.get(file -> {
    if (correlationId.equals(Arrays.stream(keys).map(file::getAttribute).collect(Collectors.joining(":"))))
        return FlowFileFilter.FlowFileFilterResult.ACCEPT_AND_CONTINUE;
    return FlowFileFilter.FlowFileFilterResult.REJECT_AND_CONTINUE;
});
```

Again with 33k waiting in the queue I was expecting around 200 new grouped flow files but 320 is created. It looks like a similar issue above and does not scan all waiting flow files on filter query.

**Problems-Question:**

Is there a parameter to change so this getObjectCount can take up to 300k?

Is there a way to filter all waiting flow files again by changing a parameter or by changing the processor?

- I tried making default queue threshold 300k on nifi.properties but it didn't help

Comment: What do you mean by `group` flow files? Reorder them in queue? Could you explain why routeOnattribute is not working for you.

Comment: @daggett Literally grouping by these attributes and they can be processed together. Basically I need to access to all matching flow files and run some logic on them. You can check solution 2 for the current implementation. Attribute values will be something like `date` and `partner_id`. Can't really put these into RouteOnAttribute and even if I did it will be like 400 different relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `nifi.properties` there is a parameter that affects batching behavior

```
nifi.queue.swap.threshold=20000
```

here is my test flow:

```
 1. GenerateFlowFile with "batch size = 50K"
 2. ExecuteGroovyScript with script below
 3. LogAttrribute (disabled) - just to have queue after groovy
```

groovy script:

```js
def ffList = session.get(100000) // get batch with maximum 100K files from incoming queue
if(!ffList)return

def ff = session.create()        // create new empty file
ff.batch_size = ffList.size()    // set attribute to real batch size

session.remove(ffList)           // drop all incoming batch files
REL_SUCCESS << ff                // transfer new file to success
```

with parameters above there are 4 files generated in output:

```
1. batch_size = 20000
2. batch_size = 10000
3. batch_size = 10000
4. batch_size = 10000
```

according to [documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/nifi-in-depth.html#DeeperView):

> There is also the notion of "swapping" FlowFiles. This occurs when the number of FlowFiles in a connection queue exceeds the value set in the `nifi.queue.swap.threshold` property. The FlowFiles with the lowest priority in the connection queue are serialized and written to disk in a "swap file" in batches of 10,000.

This explains that from 50K incoming files - 20K it keeps inmemory and others in swap batched by 10K.

---

i don't know how increasing of `nifi.queue.swap.threshold` property will affect your system performance and memory consumption, but i set it to 100K on my local nifi 1.16.3 and it looks good with multiple small files, and first batch increased to 100K by this.

Comment: cheers. this was the parameter I was looking for. 
 I'll check big numbers and see if it will cause any issues for performance.